# Find all child nodes for any parent node in Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

My table structure is:

```
COMPANY_ID, ID, PARENT_ID
```

Here is some part from this table:

```
     | COMPANY_ID |     ID      |  PARENT_DID |
     |------------|-------------|-------------|
     | 12         |      1      |    null     |
     | 12         |      3      |     1       |
     | 12         |      2      |     1       |
     | 12         |      4      |     3       |
     | 12         |      7      |     4       |
     | 14         |      3      |     null    |
```

I want to find all child and grandchild IDs for any ID in Oracle 10g. The result must be like this for COMPANY_ID=12 and ID=3:

> 3, 4, 7

I have tried this, but this not working:

```
SELECT id
FROM TABLE_NAME
  START WITH ID        = 3
  CONNECT BY PARENT_ID = PRIOR ID
AND COMPANY_ID=12;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to restrict it to the same company ID with another PRIOR clause, and move the specific company ID you're looking for into the START WITH clause:

```
SELECT id
FROM TABLE_NAME
START WITH ID = 3 AND COMPANY_ID = 12
CONNECT BY PARENT_ID = PRIOR ID AND COMPANY_ID = PRIOR COMPANY_ID;

        ID
----------
         3 
         4 
         7
```

If you specify multiple starting IDs (as you mentioned in a comment) you might get duplicates, which you could suppress with DISTINCT; but if you wanted to see which descendants were releated to which of your starting IDs, there's a handy [`connect_by_root` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/operators004.htm) that leats you keep track of that; for example:

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT id AS root_id, id AS id
FROM TABLE_NAME
START WITH ID IN (3, 7)
AND COMPANY_ID = 12
CONNECT BY PARENT_ID = PRIOR ID and COMPANY_ID = PRIOR COMPANY_ID;

   ROOT_ID         ID
---------- ----------
         3          3 
         3          4 
         3          7 
         7          7
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That's all. It works fine. Is there any problem if I want to retreieve child id's for more than one parent id like that: `START WITH ID  IN (3,15,18)`?

Comment: @EzioAuditoredaFirenze - you could get duplicates depending on your structure, so you might need to add DISTINCT. Other than that I think that's fine.

Comment: @EzioAuditoredaFirenze - I've added a note about another option that might be useful if you're starting with multiple IDs; depends if you'd want to know what was related to each one.